# Is $\int_{0}^{x}{\sin(t^2)dt}$ bounded in $[0,\infty)$?

Tags: integration

I have bene trying to figure out if the below is bounded in the domain $[0,\infty)$ $$\int_{0}^{x}{\sin(t^2)dt}$$
Can anyone give me a clue? thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting $u=t^2$? After that do integration by parts on $[1,x]$.

Comment: I believe that this integral is a nonelementary integral

Comment: It does not matter, you just need to show that it is bounded.

Comment: It is clearly enough to show that the integral from $1$ to $x$ is bounded for $x>1$. Proceeding as I suggested $$
\int_1^x {\sin (t^2 )dt}  = \frac{1}{2}\int_1^{x^2 } {\frac{{\sin (u)}}{{\sqrt u }}du}  = \frac{{\cos (x^2 )}}{{2x}} - \frac{{\cos (1)}}{2} - \frac{1}{4}\int_1^{x^2 } {\frac{{\cos (u)}}{{u^{3/2} }}du} .
$$ Can you show that the last integral is bounded for $x>1$?

Comment: Yes I managed to do it. Thanks a lot for helping me out :)

Comment: So, this integration by parts proves more: not only is it bounded, the improper integral $\int_0^\infty\sin(t^2)\,dt$ converges.